# How to get Images from Database using Breeze?

Tags: knockout.js, breeze

We have Images stored in SQL Server database, I use HotTowel's template(thanks to John Papa)
My Model is like this:

```
 public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ProductName{ get; set; }
    [DataType("image")]
    public Byte[] ImageData { get; set; }
}
```

I use Breeze Api Controller :

```
public IQueryable<Product> Products()
    {
        return _contextProvider.Context.Products;
    }
```

Client Code:

```
var getProductPartials = function (productObservable)
{
 var query = EntityQuery.from('Products')
            .select('id, productName,imageData')
             .take(10);

        return manager.executeQuery(query)
            .then(querySucceeded)
            .fail(queryFailed);

        function querySucceeded(data) {
            var list = partialMapper.mapDtosToEntities(
                manager, data.results, entityNames.product, 'id');
            if (productObservable) {
                productObservable(list);
            }
            log('Retrieved [Products] from remote data source',
                data, true);
        }
}
```

The problem is that I couldn't bind the image data to the UI.

Viewing the Metadata:

```
"Id":1,"ProductName":"Product A","ImageData":{"$type":"System.Byte[],   mscorlib","$value":"/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/4SOMRXhpZgAASUkqA etc...
```

Debugging shows me no Image data from (e.results):

```
imageData: Object 
__proto__: Object
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Four months have past since I posted this question, until I diceded to make more testing on this issue.

The Ironic part, is that I managed to bind the image data to the UI by neglecting projection query:

Modified the client code to:

```
var getProductPartials = function (productObservable){
var query = EntityQuery.from('Products').take(10);
       // .select('id, productName,imageData'); Removing this solved the proplem

    return manager.executeQuery(query)
        .then(querySucceeded)
        .fail(queryFailed);

    function querySucceeded(data) {
      //  var list = partialMapper.mapDtosToEntities(
        //    manager, data.results, entityNames.product, 'id');
        if (productObservable) productObservable(data.results);

        log('Retrieved [Products] from remote data source',
            data, true);
    }
```

}

Then Binding:

```
<img data-bind="attr: { src: 'data:image/png;base64,' + imageData() }" />
```

For some reason, Image data is not shown when making a projection query.

I hope that helps someone with the same situation.